# type object 'Post' has no attribute 'published' django by exapmle book

Tags: python, django

I'm following Django by example book first chapter and when I'm trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/` i got this error
`type object 'Post' has no attribute 'published'`

and in the terminal it says this is the error
`File "/Users/ziad/Documents/code/blog/mysite/blog/views.py", line 6, in post_list posts = Post.published.all()`

but i can't figure out what is the issue i double checked the code and everything is fine

this is my views.py

`def post_list(request): posts = Post.published.all() return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'posts': posts})`

models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'), )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250) 
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish') 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
    choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
```

```py
 class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
```

```py
objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
```

Comment: Share the `Post` model.

Comment: alright i shared it

Comment: the `published` must be *indented*: it should be a member of the `Post` class.

Comment: i believe it is indented

Comment: Your model has `publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) `, but your query is `posts = Post.published.all()`, so it should be `posts = Post.publish.all()`

Comment: didn't work i just copied this code from the book bytheway but i don't know why it's not working